# Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY'

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc

A while ago, I got this error from one of my ASP.NET MVC application, I didn't do any update on it but now I get this error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.UpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY'
```

I execute this query `show engines;` and the result is as below:

[image]

I also execute this query `SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM 'shandiznl';` and as you see, all my table listed as `InnoDB` engine.

[image]

I also updated MySQL packages as below:

```
  <package id="MySql.Data" version="8.0.20" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Data.EntityFramework" version="8.0.20" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="MySql.Web" version="8.0.20" targetFramework="net46" />
```

but I still get *Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY'* on updating my tables.

table DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE `Customers` (
`Id` char(36) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`FirstName` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`LastName` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`MobileNumber` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Address` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PostalCode` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`City` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`Email` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`ConfirmEmail` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
`Password` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`PasswordSalt` longblob DEFAULT NULL,
`CreatedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
`IsDeleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
UNIQUE KEY `IX_Email` (`Email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

what should I do?

Comment: Look in your MySQL error log for errors. This will be a server side fault of some sort (most likely). The [memory engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/memory-storage-engine.html) is still there in MySQL-8.0 that you are using.

Comment: Firstly you must understand does the error "Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY'" is produced by MySQL or by application code. *get Unknown storage engine 'MEMORY' on updating my tables.* Show the code - how do you try to update your table(s). And show table's DDL.

Comment: @Akina The way I update my tables hasn't changed since I lunch my web site and it was working fine until recently

Comment: I execute `select version()` and this is the result: `10.4.13-MariaDB-log`, Could this be the problem?

Comment: I tested my program with sql server and it's working without any errors.

Comment: I have updated all NuGet packages and it seems that the problem solved